# Can't start rails server after aws-sdk-3 installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-ruby

I know that there is a lot of such kind of questions, but still, I believe my case is slightly different. 
I recently decided to build in an AWS-S3 gem to my rails version 3 project (RUBY_VERSION - 1.9.2p320).
After the successfully aws-sdk gem have been installed, I've got an error message on `rails server`

```
/root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.78.0/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/patches.rb:26:in `alias_method': undefined method `new_transport_request' for class `Net::HTTP' (NameError)
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.78.0/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/patches.rb:26:in `apply!'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.78.0/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/connection_pool.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.78.0/lib/seahorse.rb:34:in `require_relative'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.78.0/lib/seahorse.rb:34:in `<top (required)>'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `block in require'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:597:in `new_constants_in'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.78.0/lib/aws-sdk-core.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `block in require'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:597:in `new_constants_in'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-resources-3.59.0/lib/aws-sdk-resources.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `block in require'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:597:in `new_constants_in'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-3.0.1/lib/aws-sdk.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
from /jasa/api/trunk/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.19/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.19/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.19/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.19/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I've tried both

```
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 3'
```

and

```
gem 'aws-sdk-s3', '~> 1'
```

I've checked the [referred module](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/master/gems/aws-sdk-core/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/patches.rb) in github, but got hothing to catch on.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks a lot. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's clear based on [referred module](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/master/gems/aws-sdk-core/lib/seahorse/client/net_http/patches.rb) that you posted in your question. If you see the code `new_transport_request` method is defined in `module Ruby_2` (line 30) and `module Ruby_1_9_3` (line 83) and then if you see line 19 to 24 :

```
if RUBY_VERSION >= '2.0'
  Net::HTTP.send(:include, Ruby_2)
  Net::HTTP::IDEMPOTENT_METHODS_.clear
elsif RUBY_VERSION >= '1.9.3'
  Net::HTTP.send(:include, Ruby_1_9_3)
end
```

there is no if condition for ruby 1.9.2. In conclusion the issue is not coming from Ruby or Rails but from the gem that does not support ruby 1.9.2.

You might just need to `upgrade the ruby to 1.9.3` and it should fix this issue. Furthermore ruby 1.9.2 is no longer maintained so it's good idea to upgrade to avoid security vulnerability. I hope it's help.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, @surga.
After a bit of investigation, I conclude that with ruby v1.9.2 it is impossible to use even aws-sdk version 2.
Only v1. And you have to specified 'nokogiri', '~> 1.5.0' to be able to install it.
But v1 is not maintained anymore and I think there will be security issues. Unfortunately to upgrade a Rails version is not an option for me, So I decided to give up using aws S3 for my rails application.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with an update to the latest rails, but incrementally, of course. ActiveStorage feature changes and the latest gem. No telling what went south since Rails 3

Comment: Thanks, @Tom Connoly. Please, see my comment to Surga's answer.